# Apache server, JSON parser

Tags: javascript, php, json, apache, mod-rewrite

I'm looking for json parser that can be used inside httpd.conf file in combination with url rewrite:

Here is the json file for the example:

```
{
  "employees": [
  { "emp1":"Andy" },
  { "emp2":"David" },
  ]
}
```

For example i got this url (http://someurl.com/employees/emp1/)

- employees is rewrite by the apache server to employees.json

So far so good if i just want the file, But lets say i want specific item as the url(http://someurl.com/employees/emp1/) show i want **emp1**:

**The first thing** i was looking is a way to fetch the item directly from the url for example to rewrite:

> http://someurl.com/employees/emp1/

To:

> http://someurl.com/employees.json:emp1/ // Just an example for a possibility that there is a syntax to fetch single item directly from the url

**Another thing** to consider is the use of PHP/JS to process the URL than parse and return the item (**emp1 value**).

**So the last thing** i was thinking is the use of JSON parser that can work inside the apache configuration file(httpd.conf) in combination with url rewrite process.

I'd love to hear what is the best solution, Thank you all and have a nice day.

Comment: Seems a totally weird approach - use plain MVC with front controller pattern and let PHP fetch the single employee data at `/employees/:d`, returning it via simply  echoing `json_encode($data)`.

Comment: Why the `javascript` tag?

Comment: Because one of the method to process other than php is on the client side using javascript.